Livewire not rendering slots
I'm trying to create a table and make the actions column flexible. I thought it is handy to use a slot for the actions so I can change it whenever the actions change. So my goal basically:
<livewire:tables.products.overview>
    <x-slot:slotName>
        Some data here
    </x-slot:slotName>
</livewire:tables.products.overview>

In the overview, I got a empty page with just the slot I want to render:
<div>
    Render the slot here: -> {{$slotName}} <-
</div>

Running this template, causes the error Undefined variable $slotName.
I decided to go back to basics and changed the overview.blade.php with just the default slot:
<div>
    Render the slot here: -> {{$slot}} <-
</div>

Then render the template as:
<livewire:tables.products.overview>
    <div>
        My slot will be placed here
    </div>
</livewire:tables.products.overview>

Also this gives me a error: Undefined variable $slot
What am I missing, what is it that I'm not seeing?

Is there any reason why you are doing it this way rather than putting your HTML inside overview.blade.php?

Livewire 3 does not support component slots

@TUPKAP how should I fix my problem? I need the same table over and over again and don't want to completely write every table again
